TORQ rdb doesn't subscribe to tp if tp fails mid-day
I am experiencing with TORQ framework from Data Intellect.
All well, but the tp failed last night and it was automatically brought up by our processes. However, rdb did not subscribe again on reconnect. Doesn't TORQ provide this functionality or should the RDB and WDB be bounced in these circumstances ?

Might be better to contact Data Intellect directly? A vanilla RDB would have to be bounced in order to reconnect and replay to catch up on any missing data. TORQ might have some functionality built in to do this

They also have a google group https://groups.google.com/g/kdbtorq
